# Setting Vue input value from method JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm setting the value of an input via JS in my Vue method. It *appears* to work. But as soon as I go to save it it only saves what I typed prior to the value being set in method. Ex: I type `new yor` and selct "New York" from options which triggers method and updates the value with the place ID for that place. But when I save the data (submit button) and exampine it in datbase it shows `new yor`. It didn't save the updated value. I know I can use @click, @change etc... but not sure if that's the best setup for this. How do I need to change my code to allow Vue to get updated value?

```
methods: {
      autocomp() {
          const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
          const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput);
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            searchInput.value = place.place_id
          })
        },
```

HTML

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input v-model="newPost.businessid" @keyup="autocomp" type="text" placeholder="Business ID" class="form-control" id="searchTextField">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

Replace

```
searchInput.value = place.place_id
```

with

```
that.newPost.businessid = place.place_id
```

Vue uses two-way data binding, so the variable's value is directly connected to the input value.

EDIT:

you have to save the reference to the Vue object as it is not accessible from the listener method as `this`

```
autocomp() {
      const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput);
    var that = this;
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        that.newPost.businessid = place.place_id
      })
    },
```

Comment: I believe your right, but when I do so. The input value isn't changing :/

Comment: Also, are you sure that you should call the Autocomp method on every keyup event?

Comment: That edit worked perfectly thanks! I'm new to the Vue events. `@keyup` was the only one that seemed to work. Would something like `@change` be better?

Comment: No, my point is only to call autocomp at the initialization phase because basically it is performing init for Google Maps API and setting an event listener, which are tasks that are to be executed only once

Comment: Maybe in the `mounted()` function of the component

Comment: Ah! Good to know! I need to look more into mounted() have never used it